# ServerSocket while not breaks on image data inputstream

Tags: java, android, io, java-io

I tried to send an image from One device to other Device using Bluetooth.For that I take Android Bluetooth chat application source code and it works fine when I send String.But If i send image as byte array the while loop not breaks or EOF not reached when read from Inputstream.

**Model:1**

It receives image properly.But here I need to pass resultByteArray length.But I dont know the length.How to know the length of byte array in inputstream? inputstream.available() returns 0.

```
while(true)
{
    byte[] resultByteArray = new byte[150827];
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
    dataInputStream.readFully(resultByteArray);

    mHandler.obtainMessage(AppConstants.MESSAGE_READ, dataInputStream.available(),-1, resultByteArray).sendToTarget();
}
```

**Model:2**

In this code while loop not breaks,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] resultByteArray = new byte[1024];

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = mmInStream.read(resultByteArray)) != -1) {
    Log.i("BTTest1", "bytesRead=>"+bytesRead);
    bao.write(resultByteArray,0,bytesRead);
}

final byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();
```

Also tried `byte[] resultByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(mmInStream);`but it also not works.I followed [Bluetooth chat sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat/BluetoothChatService.java).

How to solve this issue?

Comment: does your server close its output stream? If it should not close it, you may first transmit the length, then the data.

Comment: No,my client didn't close outputstream after write image byte array to outputstream. Is it any sample code to write the length?

Comment: _convert an integer to a byte array_ (you may search for that phrase) and write it to the stream.

Comment: Yes,but on receiver side how to differentiate the int data and image data?

Comment: No way; you just know that it is sent first. Just like if you needed to send two images (first the first one, then the second). But why don't you want to close the connection?

Comment: I get OutputStream on constructor of ConnectedThread.This thread is started on app launch only.So If i close the  OutputStream i need to start the thread every image sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the server needs to put the length of image at front of the actual image data. And the length of the image length information should be fixed like 4 bytes.

Then in the while loop, you need to get 4 bytes first to figure out the length of the image. After that, read bytes of the exact length from the input stream. That is the actual image.

The while loop doesn't need to break during the connection is alive. Actually it needs to wait another image data in the same while loop. The `InputStream.read()` is a blocking function and the thread will be sleeping until it receives enough data from the input stream.

And then you can expect another 4 bytes right after the previous image data as a start of another image.

```
while(true) {
    try {
        // Get the length first
        byte[] bytesLengthOfImage = new byte[4];
        mmInStream.read(bytesLengthOfImage);
        int lengthOfImage = 0;
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesLengthOfImage);
            buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);  // Assume it is network byte order.
            lengthOfImage = buffer.getInt();
        }

        byte[] actualImage = new byte[lengthOfImage];   // Mind the memory allocation.
        mmInStream.read(actualImage);

        mHandler.obtainMessage(AppConstants.MESSAGE_READ, lengthOfImage,-1, actualImage).sendToTarget();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof IOException) {
            // If the connection is closed, break the loop.
            break;
        }
        else {
            // Handle errors
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a kind of simplified communication protocol. There is an open source framework for easy protocol implementation, called NFCommunicator.

https://github.com/Neofect/NFCommunicator

It might be an over specificiation for a simple project, but is worth a look.